# How to well organize elements (jsx/css) in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to create something that look like a mockup that I designed, but it start being messy, and it is hard for me to organize each elements as I wish to.

This is what I'd like to display with my code:

[image]

This is what I succeeded to display with my code:

[image]

But I feel my code is getting too complicated and I can't continue this way. I feel I'm on the bad way, in fact, so I ask to you some help.

Here is my **JS code**:

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './BdrTargets.module.css';

const bdrTargetsComponentFunc = (props) => {

    return(
        <div>
            <h1 className={classes.FirstTitle}>BDR targets</h1>
            <div className={classes.FirstSquare}>
                <h3 className={classes.ProgressTarget}>progress vs target</h3>

                <div className={classes.Container}>
                    <p className={classes.LineName}>opportunities number</p>
                    <p className={classes.LineName}>total ACV</p>
                    <p className={classes.LineName}>total potential ACV</p>
                    <p className={classes.LineName}>total closing</p>
                    <p className={classes.LineName}>average notes quality grades</p>
                </div>
                
                <div className={classes.Container2}>        
                    <p className={classes.ProgressTargetItem}>progress_bar</p>
                </div>    
                    <h3 className={classes.WeeklyGoal}></h3>
                    <h3 className={classes.Monthly}></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default bdrTargetsComponentFunc;
```

And this is my **CSS**:

```
.FirstTitle{
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 320px;
    font-family: system-ui, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", sans-serif;
    font-size: 29px;
    color: #262e39;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.FirstSquare{
    margin-left: 320px;
    height:350px;
    width: 1500px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(173, 173, 173, 0.2);
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    /* background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #323E4D , #1E252E); */
}

.ProgressTarget{
    font-family: system-ui, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #262e39;
    font-weight: 800;
    margin-left:330px;
    width: 200px;
    /* border-right: 1px solid rgba(173, 173, 173, 0.6); */
}

.ProgressTargetItem{
    float:left;
    padding-left: 280px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.LineName{
    width: 210px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top:10px;
    font-family: system-ui, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", sans-serif;
    color: #262e39;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.Container{
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
}

.Container2{
    float:inline-end;
}
```

Thank you **very very much** for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React it is recommended to use [Composition](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#extracting-components) a lot:

> Don’t be afraid to split components into smaller components

#### For example:

*(this is not the full code, it only should illustrate the idea)*

```
const BdrTargetTitle = (props)=>{
    return (<h1 className={classes.FirstTitle}>{ props.children }</h1>);
};

const BdrTargetContent = (props)=>{
    return (<div className={classes.FirstSquare}>{ props.children }</div>);
};

const ProgressBar = (props)=>{
    return (<p className={classes.ProgressTargetItem}>progress_bar</p>);
};

const BdrView = (props) => {
    return(
        <div>
            <BdrTargetTitle>
                BDR targets
            </BdrTargetTitle>
            <BdrTargetContent>
                { props.children }
            </BdrTargetContent>
        </div>
    )
};

const BdrTargetsComponentFunc = (props) => {
  return(
    <BdrView>
        <BdrProgressVsTarget />
    </BdrView>
  );
};
```

Of course, the component structure in my example probably doesn't make sense for your use case. You know your project better to make up a meaningful structure.

The components should be organized by semantic (by meaning) not by style. E.g.:

**good:**

```
<MyView>
  <GenericMainHeader />
  <MyInfobox>
    <GenericTitle />
    <InfoItems />
  </MyInfobox>
</MyView>
```

**bad:**

```
<FullScreenBox>
  <Headline className={ big } />
  <BlackOutlineBox>
    <Headline className={ small } />
    <Grid3by5 />
  </BlackOutlineBox>
</FullScreenBox>
```

#### Files

It is also good to put each component into an own file, e.g.:
progressbar.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
const ProgressBar = (props)=>{
    return (<p className={classes.ProgressTargetItem}>progress_bar</p>);
};
export default Progressbar;

// alternatively:
// export const ProgressBar = (props)=>{ ...
```

#### Experience

To create a meaningful hierarchy of your components (and folder structure), I think you just need some experience. Be prepared to change your mind a few times, and probably having to change (parts of) the structure.

#### Grid

Maybe you also want to use [css-grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)